# Retrofit Request Interceptor blocks the main thread

Tags: android, retrofit, networkonmainthread

This issue has already been mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22016657/blocking-request-interceptor-with-retrofit/22229471#22229471), but it is a quite old question and I couldn't find any other information.

The Request Interceptor of a Retrofit API call is executed on the main thread. This is an issue when dealing with AccountManager to add auth tokens to the request header, like

```
String token = mAccountManager.blockingGetAuthToken(account, AuthConsts.AUTH_TYPE, false);
```

Same issue is discussed on [G+](https://plus.google.com/106567625933758304961/posts/a18m1XavSus) and there is a related issue on GitHub [here](https://github.com/square/retrofit/issues/261).

While this all gets worked (thanks SquareUp!), what is the best way to work around it? Wrapping the Retrofit calls in an AsyncTask or similar feels like invalidating the whole idea.

Comment: Retrofit's job is *not* to move network calls off the main thread. It is simply to provide an interface to a Rest service. I used [this](https://github.com/paristote/youcast-android/blob/master/src/com/philipoy/youtubedl/rest/YouCastInterface.java) approach in a project recently to add a request interceptor to every call made with Retrofit.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Retrofit's interceptor is for modifying the request with known information. That is to say that it should be a simple and instance transformation.

The best approach for what you are looking for is to use [OkHttp's interceptors](https://github.com/square/okhttp/wiki/Interceptors) to add the header. These will run on the background thread.

```
class AuthInterceptor implements Interceptor {
  @Override public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
    Request request = chain.request();

    String authHeader = // TODO get auth token
    request = request.builder()
      .header("Authorization", authHeader)
      .builder();

    return chain.proceed(request);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could simple use `peekAuthToken` to get the token and only if the result is `null` would you need to "refresh" the token you could then either let the request fail or asynchronously get the new token