# Kotlin runBlocking always blocks main thread?

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit2, kotlin-coroutines

[The official document about runBlokcing](https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/run-blocking.html) says

> Runs a new coroutine and blocks the current thread until its
> completion. This function should not be used from a coroutine. It is
> designed to bridge regular blocking code to libraries that are written
> in suspending style, to be used in main functions and in tests.

I think it means that `runBlocking` blocks only current thread.

but the `Kotlin Coroutines Deep Dive` by written `Marcin Moskała`.
In the book, it says

> "Using a dispatcher, we can make runBlocking run on a different
> thread. But still, the thread on which this builder has been started
> will be blocked until the coroutines is done."

I understood it even if i change the current thread to worker(or other) thread with `withContext` or something and run the 'runBlocking' in the worker thread, the `runBlocking` will still block all the thread including main thread.

Therefore, what i want to know is `runBlocking` always block the main thread no matter what ways i use?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`runBlocking` only blocks a single thread, the one that it was called on.

The book quote doesn’t contradict the documentation. Maybe your source of confusion about what the book is saying is thinking “the coroutine” in the phrase “until the coroutine is done” is referring to the outer coroutine that (shamefully) called `runBlocking`, when it is actually referring to the (unrelated) new coroutine that `runBlocking` builds.

You should never use `runBlocking` inside a coroutine in the first place. There is no situation or condition where it would ever make sense to do that. *Almost* the only two places you will ever use `runBlocking` is directly in a JVM’s `main()` function or in a unit test. But also you might need it to use coroutines synchronously in a non-suspending callback function.

Comment: Thank you.
As you said, i think I was confused because of that sentence. Technically, i was reading a part of using `runblocking` in `main()` function. So, there is no reason to use `runBlocking` in a coroutine. :) but i have a question. i can see some questions that they want to use `runBlocking` in Retrofit `interceptor` or `Authenticator`. Do you think it's fine? because if i use `runBlocking` in them, it might block main thread.

Comment: It depends on whether the interceptor or Authenticator interfaces are called on the main thread or not. I’m not familiar enough with Retrofit to know under which conditions they will be called on the main thread. Maybe this is relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/q/28021485/506796

Comment: Oh, so the book quote is talking about changing the dispatcher used internally by the runBlocking coroutine to run its code. Sometimes you want to do that if you need to do parallel *blocking* work so you need more than one thread working.

Comment: Yes. as you mentioned, the book and document are right. the only problem was that i misunderstood the content of the book. haha
So, what i wanted to try was like below.
`fun main() {
    val thread = Thread {
            runBlocking(Dispatchers.IO) {
                println("my thread")
            }
        }
    thread.start()
    println("End")
}
`
// my thread
// End
`runBlocking` that is in the new `Thread` only blocks the new thread not main thread. So, it's fine.  And if i use Retrofit, It should be fine as long as it operates on the worker thread. Thank you Tenfour04 :-)

Answer (score 6):

Those quotes both say it blocks the current thread.  Which is what it does.  If you use it on the main thread, then it blocks the main thread.  If you use it on another thread, it blocks that one.

Comment: I suppose this is correct, but in this confusing (for newcomers) situation, "the current thread" and "use it on" are not very clear as to whether you mean the thread being used outside of `runBlocking` or the one on which the new coroutine is run. (Just as the official documentation is not unambiguous as to what "the current thread" refers to). I'm pretty sure it means the thread being used outside of `runBlocking`, but since this confusion is a key part of the OP's question, it would help to be unambiguous.